# Extrude on objects Z axis

Tags: extrude, axis

I don't know why but sometimes when i try to extrude it extrudes on the objects Z axis but sometimes it doesn't,
someone knows why? i need to extrude always on objects Z axis
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you extrude a face, then by default, it is extruded along its normal (the direction in which the face is pointing). If you want to extrude it specifically along the z-axis then you just have to click the z key twice(Coz if you click z just once then the extruded face will move according to your mouse pointer). But please keep in mind that by doing this it will move on the global z axis. If you have rotated the object then the z-axis of that object also gets rotated. If you want the extrusion to occur in local space(that is according to the orientation of axes after rotation) then you have to change the orientaion before extruding, by clicking the comma(",") key and changing the orientation to local. After this you can simply click e to extrude and then the z key twice. And now the extrusion will occur in the direction of the local z axis.